# mi carrusel de boobstrap no funciona

Tags: php

Warning: dir(images/prooductos/1/): El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especifica (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\details.php on line 43

Warning: dir(images/prooductos/1/): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\details.php on line 43

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function read() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\details.php:45 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\details.php on line 45

codigo php:

```
<?php

require 'config/config.php';
require 'config/database.php';

$db = new Database();
$con = $db->conectar();

$id =  isset( $_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''; 
$token =  isset( $_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : '';

if ($id == '' || $token == '') {
  
  echo "Error al procesar la petición";
  exit;

}else{

  $token_tmp = hash_hmac('sha1', $id, KEY_TOKEN);

  if ($token == $token_tmp) {

    $sql = $con ->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM productos WHERE id =? AND activo =1");
    $sql -> execute([$id]);
    if ($sql -> fetchColumn() > 0) {
      
      $sql = $con ->prepare("SELECT nombre, descripcion, precio, descuento FROM productos WHERE id =? AND activo =1");
      $sql -> execute([$id]);
      $row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $nombre = $row['nombre'];
      $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
      $precio = $row['precio'];
      $desc = $row['descuento'];
      $descuento = $precio -(($precio * $desc)/100);
      $dir_images= 'images/prooductos/'.$id.'/';
      $rutaimg = $dir_images.'principal.png';

      if (!file_exists($rutaimg)) {
        $rutaimg = "images/productos/default.png";
      }

      $imagenes = array();
      $dir = dir($dir_images);

      while (($archivo = $dir -> read()) != false) {
        
        if ($archivo != 'principal.png' && (strpos($archivo, 'png'))) {

          $imagenes[] = $dir_images.$archivo;
          
        }

      }
      $dir->close();

    }
    
    
  }else{
    echo "Error al procesar la petición";
    exit;
  }

}




?>
```

Codigo del carrusel:

```
    <div id="carouselImages" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..."  alt="...">

      <img src="<?php echo $rutaimg; ?>" alt="" width="400px" height="250px" class="d-block w-100">

    </div>

    <?php foreach($imagenes as $img) { ?>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..."  alt="...">

      <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="" width="400px" height="250px" class="d-block w-100">


    </div>

    <?php } ?>

  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselImages" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselImages" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

    

    </div>
```

Comment: pon el codigo para que te podamos ayudar, aun que el problema en si es de rutas de tu directorio

Comment: es que soy nuevo y cuando pongo el codigo me aparece error y no me deja ponerlo sabes como puedo ponerlo ?

Comment: La ruta es así **prooductos** con 2 o???